# How make the XML parsing stored procedure run faster

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure shown here; it searches the XML column that the type is (`TEXT`) and looks for input parameter to match (firstname and lastname or phone or number). The problem is the stored procedure in running really slowly to go through all the records. Is there anyway to make it faster? (I used cast because the column is `TEXT` type to convert it to XML and replace because some of the XMLS has extra )

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Tracker]
     @FirstName varchar(100) 
    ,@LastName  varchar(100)  
    ,@Phone     varchar(100)  
    ,@Number    varchar(100)  
 AS
 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     SELECT 
         [Id], [Type], [Response], [Modified], [Created],
         [bSalesforce], [Request], [Application_Filename], [AffiliateId] 
     FROM
         [Tracker]  
     WHERE
         CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Request AS varchar(max)), '\"', '"') AS xml).value('(/I/Credit/LoanApp/LoanRq/Applicant/Personal/Individu 
 als/Individual/GivenName/FirstName/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') = @FirstName    
         AND CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Request AS varchar(max)), '\"', '"') AS 
       xml).value('(/I/Credit/LoanApp/LoanRq/Applicant/Personal/Individu
 als/Individual/GivenName/LastName/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') = @LastName 
         OR CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Request AS varchar(max)), '\"', '"') AS 
     xml).value('(/I/Credit/LoanApp/LoanRq/Applicant/Personal/Individu
 als/Individual/phone/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') = @phone 
         OR CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Request AS varchar(max)), '\"', '"') AS xml).value('(/I/Credit/LoanApp/LoanRq/Applicant/Routing/From/Number/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') = @Number
END
```

Comment: The performance problem here is because it has to shred the xml 4 times for every single row in the table. Instead of storing the xml can you store the actual data instead? It would make your queries a LOT faster and allow some indexing.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks, the problem is that I am not allow to change anything in the table I only can write mo store proc in a way to get the best performance, any suggestion for that?

Comment: You can't make molasses fast on the Alaskan tundra in February. The way this table is structured is the problem. There really isn't anything you can do that query to make it faster.